# How to run a script with optional parameters?

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-powershell

I would like to run a script which creates a VM in Azure.

These are the mandatory parameters:

```
$cred = Get-Credential -Message "Enter a username and password for the virtual machine."
$RG = 'AZ-PS-RG'
$VM_NAME = 'AZ-PS-VM'
$location = 'francecentral'
$image = 'UbuntuLTS'
$size = 'Standard_D2s_v3'
$vnetName='myVNet'
$SubnetName = 'mySubnet-ps'
```

I would also like to provide two optional parameters for `PublicIpAddressName` and `DomainNameLabel`:

```
$dnsName=''
$reservedIP= ''
```

The idea is that the script should check if those parameters are empty or not. If they are empty then simply create a VM with only mandatory parameters:

```
$vmParams = @{
  ResourceGroupName = $RG
  Name = $VM_NAME
  Location = $location
  ImageName = $image
  Credential = $cred
  VirtualNetworkName = $vnetName
  SubnetName = $SubnetName
  Size = $size
  # these two I would like to run only if they are provided
  PublicIpAddressName = $reservedIP
  DomainNameLabel = $dnsName

}
$newVM1 = New-AzVM @vmParams
```

If they are not, I would like to create the VM with these two additional parameters.

Does anyone know how to do it in Powershell?

Comment: And which parameters on `New-AzVM` would you like to bind/map `$dnsName` and `$reservedIP` to, if present?

Comment: Yes, exactly @MathiasR.Jessen. I want these  parametrs to be optional while creating VM

Comment: But _which parameters_? `New-AzVM` has neither a `-dnsName` nor a `-reservedIP` parameter defined?

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen
`-PublicIpAddressName = $reservedIP` and 
`-DomainNameLabel = $dnsName`

Comment: Inside the Hash for splatting, you do not use the hyphen in front of the parameter name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a simple `if` statement to conditionally add entries to the splatting table:

```
if(-not [string]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($dnsName)){
    $vmParams['DomainNameLabel'] = $dnsName
}

if(-not [string]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($reservedIP)){
    $vmParams['PublicIpAddressName'] = $reservedIP
}
```